# Accessing a virtual token in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

In the Rails Tutorial Chapter 8 it is tested that the 'remember me' checkbox is working.

In a real contest, if a user checks the 'remember me' checkbox in the login page, after login the create action of the sessions controller uses the `remember(user)` helper, which creates a `remember_token` for the user and update the `remember_digest` attribute in the user model (via the `remember` method in user.rb), then sets `cookies[:user_id] = user.id` and `cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token`.

The book says that in the test "Ideally, we would check that the cookie’s value is equal to the user’s remember token, but as currently designed there’s no way for the test to get access to it: the user variable in the controller has a remember token attribute, but (because remember_token is virtual) the @user variable in the test doesn’t".

The test is defined below:

```
def setup
  @user = users(:michael)
end

test "login with remembering" do
  log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
  assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
end
```

First of all, considering how `cookies['remember_token']` is defined (`cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token`), if it is true that we cannot access the remember token attribute, I wonder how can we check that `cookies['remember_token']` is not nil.

Although the fixtures do not define any remember token for user michael, the `log_in_as` test helper method is defined to post to the login_path correct values for params[:session], so I am wondering: aren't these values taken by the create action of the sessions controller? If this is the case, then the create action should do the same job as described above for the real contest: the `remember(user)` helper would create a `remember_token` for the user and we could check if `cookies['remember_token'] = user.remember_token`.

I do not understand why we should not be able to access `user.remember_token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user` is created through a fixture. The issue is, `#remember_token` is a virtual attribute, which means it does not map to a database column. It gets set only when the `#remember` function is called on a `User` instance, and when that instance dies, it dies with it (though a digest of it is saved in the database, and an encrypted version of it is saved in the user's cookies).

What you are doing there using the `#log_in_as` is that, first you create a `User`, and then in the `#log_in_as` you take that user's email address and password, and send it to the controller. The controller finds that user from the database using the email that you provided, and goes ahead and calls the `#remember` function on that instance.

As you can see, the `#remember` function has never been called on your `@user` instance, so it never received the `remember_token`. But through that controller action, a cookie is set and a digest is saved in the database. So what you test there is to check if the cookie is set or not.

If you want to be more meticulous, I guess another thing you can do is to check if the digest of the cookie is the same as the digest in the database.

Comment: So if it is correct, calling 'user.remember token' does not have sense when user is from fixtures, but have sense when with assigns(:user) we access to @user (and @user.remeber_token) inside the create action of the controller.

Comment: `@user` that is created from the fixture, and the `user` in the controller are separate instances of `User`, even though their representation in the database is the same. When `user.remember` is called, it creates the token and saves it in that virtual attribute. When the controller is done, the `user` instance and the virtual attribute in it dies together. Then you go back to your test and you still have the `@user` instance there. But that never had the `remember_token` virtual attribute in the first place, so you can't access it as it it is `nil`.